# How can I add CORS functionality into my http-gateway (spring-integration-dsl)?

Tags: reactjs, cors, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have got a reactjs frontend which sends a request to my api based on spring-integration.

The problem I got is, that I don't know how to bind the CORS functionality in my gateway.

I tried something like this

```
  @Bean
    public CrossOrigin cors(){
        CrossOrigin c = new CrossOrigin();
        c.setOrigin("/**");
        return c;
    }
```

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow httpGetTest() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(httpGetGateTest()).channel("http.test.channel").handle("testEndpoint", "hello").get();
    }
```

```
@Bean
    public MessagingGatewaySupport httpGetGateTest() {
        HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway handler = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway();
        handler.setRequestMapping(createMapping(new HttpMethod[]{HttpMethod.GET}, "/test"));
        handler.setCrossOrigin(cors());
        handler.setHeaderMapper(headerMapper());
        return handler;
    }
```

Request:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/test')
    .then(res=>{console.log(res)})
```

My endpoint returns "Hello World"

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 ()
```

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please, be sure that your client really send an `Origin` HTTP request header.
Otherwise the CORS filtering is not applied to the request: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Although it sounds like it is there anyway: `from origin 'http://localhost:3000'`.

Consider to change your `setOrigin("/**")` to the `setOrigin("*")`. The Cross-Origin policy is about the whole ULR (domain to be precise), not relative path.

BTW, there is a Java DSL factory in Spring Integration for HTTP components:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpGetTest() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/test")
                .requestMapping(r -> r.methods(HttpMethod.GET))
                .crossOrigin(cors -> cors.origin("*"))
                .headerMapper(headerMapper()))
          .channel("http.test.channel")
          .handle("testEndpoint", "hello")
          .get();
}
```